# Bootstrap table nested

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to make nested table with Bootstrap:

```
| User name |  Email  |  User Phone
-----------------------------------
| user 01   |  mail01 |  060060060
| user 02   |  mail02 |  060060060
-----------------------------------
| User 02 Details -> HOW TO MAKE THIS TD? ***
-----------------------------------
| user 03   |  mail03 |  060060060
```

If I try to enter in this way the all table resizes in a wierd way acording to width of that detail TD:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Mail</td>
        <td>Phone</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>User 01</td>
            <td>Mail 01</td>
            <td>060060060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User 02</td>
            <td>Mail 02</td>
            <td>060060060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User 02 Details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User 03</td>
            <td>Mail 03</td>
            <td>060060060</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How to fix this so the whole table stays same just insert that one row of 100% width of a page?

Comment: To me it looks just like I would expect here: http://jsbin.com/kopoheda/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

It's basic HTML, [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) will let you span one column over several:

```
<td colspan="3">...</td>
```

You can see the answer on http://jsbin.com/wecovutira/1/edit?html,output